# Is there a way to make a JMX connection, over SSH, to a remote process running inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, ssh, jmx, ssh-tunnel, docker-container

I'm trying to establish a JMX connection, over SSH tunnel, to a process running inside a remote docker container. From Java Mission Control, VisualVM or JConsole the connection times out and I'm unable to connect.

The JMX connection is established if I connect, in JConsole (or any of the others), directly to the remote machine ip. The problem arises when I use a SSH tunnel.

I'm establishing an SSH tunnel from my local machine to the remote machine with

```
ssh username@remote-machine-ip -L 9090:127.0.0.1:9090
```

In the docker container I'm exposing the port 9090 and I'm using the following arguments for the JVM:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9090
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
-Djava.rmi.server.useLocalHostname=true
```

In `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname` I tried already using 127.0.0.1, localhost, the docker containers host machine ip...

In JConsole I'm using `127.0.0.1:9090` to connect.

Running tcpdump on the remote machine I'm able to capture some packets arriving at port 9090 but in JConsole it fails with "Connection failed".

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Everything was correct... more or less.
My local machine runs Windows and I was creating the SSH tunnel on Git Bash!
If I create the SSH tunnel with the Windows command line or with Putty it works just fine...